# convert dataframe column to list of string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

bust a list of string from a dataframe column like shown with my code:

```
d = {'text': ["Hello", "How are you","From","Liban"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

My list will have

```
    List_text = ["Hello","How are you","From","Liban"].
```

Thank you

Answer (score 14):

Use [`Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html):

```
list_text = df.text.tolist()

print(list_text)

['Hello', 'How are you', 'From', 'Liban']
```

Comment: Hey @Erfan I have to make a test speed on these two ^^

Comment: Sure, go ahead. Quite curious as well :)

Comment: Same stuff 831ms against 823ms with +/- 30ms so it can be a CPU performance, can't tell, but this is pretty much the same speed, I will upvote yours ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over elements in the target column and add the elements you want to an empty list.

```
d = {'text': ["Hello", "How are you","From","Liban"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
rows,columns=df.shape

list_text=[] #your empty list 
for index in range(rows): #iteration over the dataframe
    list_text.append(df.iat[index,0])

print(list_text)
```

Comment: While this command may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I will add description